# Validating Data using JS Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using javascript regex for validating user entered date in format mm/yyyy. I have made regex for this and its working fine, but when I enter ab/abcd its still validating it.

This is my JS and HTML code

```
function validate() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var pattern = /\d|\/|\d{4}/;        
    if (pattern.test(name)) {
        alert(name +" has alphanumeric value");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Name is not valid.Please input alphanumeric value!");
        return false;
    }
}
Date: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="validate();"/>
```

How can I validate the entered date in mm/yyy format, 
I am using Jquery DatePicker which allows to select date in this format, and the datepicker also allows manual input. like this [Date Picker](http://jsfiddle.net/JTL3M/11/)
Is there any alternate suggestion for this?

Comment: You want to allow the data which is in the `mm/dddd` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

Try the pattern below instead:

```
var pattern = /^\d{2}\/\d{4}$/;
```

See the working code at:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw72F/3/)

Another fiddle for extracting the month:

[JsFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw72F/11/)

Comment: Thanks its working, Can I give Number Range here? like month can be between 1-12?

Comment: Not with the regex, I believe. You might want to look at some other validation methods out there.

Comment: ok thanks, Just one more question, with this pattern if user enters 1/2014 it will not validate the month, it will only validate if he enter 01/2014, what should I do in this case

Comment: You may extract the first number before "/" and evaluate it yourself to ensure that it's between 1 and 12.

Comment: var pattern = /^\d\d?\/\d{4}$/;

Comment: See the second fiddle for extracting the month value.